# Derivation of Nyquist Frequency and Sampling Theorem

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, sampling, nyquist, theory

I have been looking through different sites and questions over the internet about Sampling theory, but couldn’t find the clear definition of how **nyquist frequency** condition is derived? It would be great if someone could direct me to the derivation of the condition that sampling frequency should >= to maximum frequency in the signal

Comment: The basic Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem is fairly well written and shows multiple ways to derive it. If you need further help please indicate which parts of the standard deviations are a problematic for you

Comment: I added a derivation from a different point of view (2 sided of the same coin of course) in comparison to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Approaching The Sampling Theorem as Inner Product Space

### Preface

There are many ways to derive the [Nyquist Shannon Sampling Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) with the constraint on the sampling frequency being 2 times the [Nyquist Frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency).
The classic derivation uses the summation of sampled series with [Poisson SummationFormula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula).

Let's introduce different approach which is more similar to function analysis - Building an orthogonal space and using projection for analysis and synthesis.

### Forming Orthonormal Basis

In this section we'll define an orthonormal base and derive the decomposition and composition process.

#### Definitions

First one should define the space of *Band Limited Functions*. The space of *Band Limited Functions* is defined by:

$$ \mathcal{B}_{ {W}_{s} } = \left\{ f \left( x \right) \mid F \left( w \right) = \mathcal{F} \left\{ f \left( x \right) \right\}, \; F \left( w \right) = 0, \; \forall \, \left| w \right| > {W}_{s} \right\} $$

In words, it means that for each function $ f \left( x \right) \in \mathcal{B}_{ {W}_{s} }$ its fourier transform $ F \left( w \right) = \mathcal{F} \left\{ f \left( x \right) \right\} $ vanishes for frequencies $ \left| w \right| > {W}_{s} $.

The inner product in this space is given by:

$$ \langle f \left( x \right), g \left( x \right) \rangle = \frac{1}{T} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f \left( x \right) g \left( x \right) dx, \; T = \frac{2 \pi}{ {W}_{s} } $$

One could easily show that this is a indeed an inner product space with valid inner product.

The main claim is the orthonormal basis of this space is given by:

$$ f \left( x \right) = \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - n T }{T} \right) $$

Where $ \operatorname{sinc} \left( x \right) $ is the [Normalized Sinc Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) given by $ \operatorname{sinc} \left( x \right) = \frac{ \sin(\pi x) }{ \pi x } $.
The basis functions are parameterized by the parameter $ n $. Basically we have shifted and scaled function as the basis.

#### Proof of The Orthonormal Property

One must show the orthonormal property of the basis under the defined inner product:

$$ \begin{aligned}
\langle f \left( x \right), g \left( x \right) \rangle & = \frac{1}{T} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f \left( x \right) g \left( x \right) dx = \frac{1}{T} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - n T }{T} \right) \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - m T }{T} \right) dx && \text{} \\
& \overset{1}{=} \frac{1}{T} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} T \Pi \left( \frac{ w }{ {W}_{s} } \right) {e}^{-j w n T} {e}^{j w t} dw \right) \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - m T }{T} \right) dx && \text{} \\
& \overset{2}{=} \frac{1}{T} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi} T \Pi \left( \frac{w}{ {W}_{s} } \right) {e}^{-j w n T} \left( \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} {e}^{j w x} \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{x - m T}{T} \right) dx \right) dw && \text{} \\
& \overset{3}{=} \frac{1}{T} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi} T \Pi \left( \frac{w}{ {W}_{s} } \right) {e}^{-j w n T} T \Pi \left( \frac{-w}{ {W}_{s} } \right) {e}^{j w m T} dw && \text{} \\
& \overset{4}{=} \frac{T}{2 \pi} \int_{ - \frac{ {W}_{s} }{2} }^{ \frac{ {W}_{s} }{2} } {e}^{j w \left( m - n \right) T} dw && \text{} \\
& \overset{5}{=} \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } m = n \\ 
0 & \text{ if } m \neq n 
\end{cases}
\end{aligned} $$

Where:

1. Since $ \mathcal{F} \left\{ \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - n T }{T} \right) \right\} = T \Pi \left( \frac{ w }{ {W}_{s} } \right) {e}^{-j w n T} $.
2. Changing order of integration for converging integrals.
3. Applying $ \mathcal{F} \left\{ \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - m T }{T} \right) \right\} \left( - w \right) $.
4. Integration boundaries according to the Rect function (Multiplication).
5. Integration over a cycle or over a constant.

Since we proved the suggested base is indeed an orthonormal basis of the space the following holds:

$$ \forall f \left( x \right) \in \mathcal{B}_{{W}_{s}} , \; f \left( x \right) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{n} \langle f \left( x \right), {g}_{n} \left( x \right) \rangle {g}_{n} \left( x \right) $$

Where $ {g}_{n} \left( x \right) = \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - n T }{T} \right) $ and $ \langle f \left( x \right), {g}_{n} \left( x \right) \rangle $ is the projection of $ f \left( x \right) $ on $ {g}_{n} \left( x \right) $.

#### Projection Process

As written above, using the result of a projection of a function in the space onto the basis one could reconstruct it as:

$$ f \left( x \right) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{n} \langle f \left( x \right), {g}_{n} \left( x \right) \rangle {g}_{n} \left( x \right) $$

The question is, what's is the projection of a general function in this space? Well, it turns out it can be shown in a sloed form way:

$$ \begin{aligned}
\langle f \left( x \right), {g}_{n} \left( x \right) \rangle & = \frac{1}{T} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f \left( x \right) {g}_{n} \left( x \right) dx = \frac{1}{T} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f \left( x \right) \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - n T }{T} \right) dx && \text{} \\
& \overset{1}{=} \frac{1}{T} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F \left( w \right) {e}^{j w x} dw \right) \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - n T }{T} \right) dx && \text{} \\
& \overset{2}{=} \frac{1}{2 \pi T} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \left( \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - n T }{T} \right) {e}^{j w x} dx \right) F \left( w \right) dw && \text{} \\
& \overset{3}{=} \frac{1}{2 \pi T} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} T \Pi \left( \frac{-w}{ {W}_{s} } \right) {e}^{j w n T} {F} \left( w \right) dw && \text{} \\
& \overset{4}{=} \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{ - \frac{ {W}_{s} }{2} }^{ \frac{ {W}_{s} }{2} } F \left( w \right) {e}^{j w n T} dw && \text{} \\
& \overset{5}{=} f \left( n T \right)
\end{aligned} $$

Where:

1. Since $ \mathcal{F} \left\{ f \left( x \right) \right\} = F \left( w \right) $.
2. Changing order of integration for converging integrals.
3. Applying $ \mathcal{F} \left\{ \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - m T }{T} \right) \right\} \left( - w \right) $.
4. Integration boundaries according to the Rect function.
5. Applying Inverse Fourier Transform at $ x = n T $.

Wrapping it yields:

$$ f \left( x \right) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{n} \langle f \left( x \right), {g}_{n} \left( x \right) \rangle {g}_{n} \left( x \right) = \sum_{n = - \infty}^{\infty} f \left( n T \right) \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - n T }{T} \right) $$

Which is known as the [Whittaker Shannon Interpolation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula).

### Conclusion

In the process above the analysis and synthesis of *Band Limited Functions* is shown using Orthonormal Basis. If one set $ T $ to be the *Sampling Interval*, usually denoted by $ {T}_{s} $ then the *Sampling Frequency* is given by $ {F}_{s} = \frac{1}{ {T}_{s} } $.
Now, since the function in frequency domain stretches in the range $ \left[ -\frac{{F}_{s}}{2}, \frac{{F}_{s}}{2} \right] $ we indeed have the known relation that the sampling frequency has to be twice the one sided support of the function in frequency.

Answer (score 3):

It really boils down to aliasing.  In continuous-time, if you have any two signals $x_1(t) = \sin(2 \pi F_1 t)$ and $x_2(t) = \sin(2 \pi F_2 t)$, then as long as $F_1$ and $F_2$ are distinct, the signals are, too.

But consider sampling at some time interval $T_s$, so that the sampled signals are $x_1(k) = \sin(2 \pi F_1 T_s k)$ and $x_2(k) = \sin(2 \pi F_2 T_s k)$.  If you have a condition where $2 \pi F_1 = 2 \pi F_2 \pm 2\pi n$ for any integer $n$, then the signals are not clearly not distinguishable, by the simple trigonometric identity $\sin \theta = \sin \theta + 2\pi$.  Do the math, and you find that the frequencies cannot be separated by more than the sampling rate to be distinguishable.

It's worse, though, because you *also* have the trigonometric identity $\sin \theta = -\sin \theta + \pi$.  When you consider that the only thing that allows you to distinguish one signal from another is the frequency, that means that if $F_2$ is a mere $\frac{1}{2 T_s}$ away from $F_1$, then $x_1(t)$ cannot be distinguished from $x_2(t)$.

This phenomenon of two distinct signals appearing as one after sampling is called *aliasing*.  It's pretty much the basis of the Shannon-Nyquist sampling theorem, and the Nyquist rate.  Because if you're sampling at $\frac{1}{T_s}$ and trying to distinguish signals further apart than $\frac{1}{2T_s}$, you just can't.

Hence, the Nyquist rate.